# How to call a Java varargs method with Scala's AnyVal?

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions, jooq

I have a Java method using the following signature (from [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)):

```
Query query(String sql, Object... bindings);
```

Now, I want to call this method inside Scala with `AnyVal`s, for example:

```
val id = 2
val value = 3.14
query(someString, id, value)
```

Doing this gives me the following compiler error:

```
Error:(34, 16) overloaded method value query with alternatives:
  (x$1: String,x$2: org.jooq.QueryPart*)org.jooq.Query <and>
  (x$1: String,x$2: Object*)org.jooq.Query
 cannot be applied to (String, Int, Double)
        create.query(someString, id, lat)
               ^
```

I can however cast each `AnyVal` explicitly to `AnyRef` to enforce autoboxing and thus remove the compiler error:

```
query(someString, id.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
```

Realizing this, I though I could write as small function that casts all objects to `AnyRef` like this:

```
def toVarargs(arg: Any, args: Any*): Array[AnyRef] = {
    (arg +: args).map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]).toArray
}

query(someString, toVarargs(id, value))
```

Sadly this does not work as well because the `Array[AnyRef]` is interpreted as a single varargs variable (changing it to `Array[Object]` does not make any difference).

One can make this work by using the `_*` operator:

```
query(someString, toVarargs(id, value): _*)
```

However, this seems rather verbose. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem or I am stuck by combining my own function with the varargs operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jOOQ 3.7, there is a new `SQLInterpolation` class in the [`Conversions` type of the jOOQ-scala extension](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.7.0/jOOQ-scala/src/main/scala/org/jooq/scala/Conversions.scala). It's essentially just:

```
implicit class SQLInterpolation(val sc : StringContext) extends AnyVal {

  def sql(args: Any*) : SQL = 
    DSL.sql(string, args.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]] : _*)

  def condition(args : Any*) : Condition = 
    DSL.condition(string, args.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]] : _*)

  def table(args : Any*) : Table[Record] = 
    DSL.table(string, args.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]] : _*)

  def query(args : Any*) : Query = 
    DSL.query(string, args.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]] : _*)

  def resultQuery(args : Any*) : ResultQuery[Record] = 
    DSL.resultQuery(string, args.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]] : _*)

  private def string = {
    val pi = sc.parts.iterator
    val sb = new StringBuilder(pi.next())
    var i = 0;

    while (pi.hasNext) {
      sb += '{'
      sb ++= (i toString)
      sb += '}'
      sb ++= pi.next()

      i = i + 1;
    }

    sb.result
  }
}
```

Using this, you should be able to write:

```
val id = 2
val value = 3.14
query"""SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = ${id} and value = ${value}"""
```

The nice thing with the above approach is that it works both with just bind values as above, or with embedded SQL:

```
val id = 2
val value = 3.14
val condition = (MY_TABLE.ID === id) and (MY_TABLE.VALUE === value)
query"""SELECT * FROM t WHERE ${condition}"""
```

Comment: This solves my initial problem. However I see that you did not find another (simpler) solution than using `args.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]] : _*`.

Also, what is the reason that you pass `args` to `string(args)` without using them? (Maybe missing a `sc.checkLengths(args)` statement?)

Comment: @r0estir0bbe: Yeah, that `sc.checkLengths(args)` call was it... It was removed in the end, as this check isn't a strict requirement for jOOQ's API

Comment: Finally I actually was able to test the string interpolation feature for jOOQ in Scala. However, I ran into the problem of not being able to set the `DSLContext`, thus receiving a `Cannot execute query. No Connection configured` error. Am I doing something wrong/is there some way to set the `DSLContext` beforehand? I tried making both a `Configuration` and a `DSLContext` implicit, but that did not work for me.

Comment: @r0estir0bbe: Hard to say from the comments. Would you mind asking a new question (with code examples)?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Link to the [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003070/how-to-use-scalas-string-interpolation-in-jooq).

Comment: @r0estir0bbe: Thanks. I see now. Perhaps there's room for improvement? [If so, let's discuss on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003773/521799)