# How to use Scala's String Interpolation in jOOQ?

Tags: scala, jooq

I would like to use the string interpolation feature of jOOQ in Scala, for example `resultQuery"SELECT * FROM objects"`:

```
// setup connection
val con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)

// create DSLContext
val dsl = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4)

// normal use of DSLContext
dsl.resultQuery("SELECT * FROM objects")

// intented use of string interpolation
val q = resultQuery"SELECT * FROM objects"

val result = q.fetch()
println(result)
```

Running this code (without any outside configuration and the like) results in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:312)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:305)
    ...
```

It seems that the `SQLInterpolation` is using the default settings. I tried to provide these settings by setting `DSLContext` as well as `Configuration` as implicits but I still received the same exception:

```
implicit val dsl = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4)
implicit val config = new DefaultConfiguration().derive(con)
                                                .derive(SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4)
```

How do I correctly provide my settings (connection, dialect, etc.) to the string interpolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResultQuery` object that you've created using string interpolation is not "attached", i.e. it cannot be executed on its own.

In other words, you should run the query like this, instead:

```
val result = dsl.fetch(q)
```

Comment: That was the missing link. I do not know how I missed that one.